# Codeigniter - change http port, redirect function fail

Tags: php, codeigniter

Due to my port 80 on my computer is blocked.

So I change my Apache config to change http port to 8899.

---

Problem here:

My original URL is http://localhost:8899/myProject/home

In controller, I use redirect function when user is not login:

```
redirect('login');
```

When I test this, the URL redirect to http://[::1]/myProject/login and show 404...

However, when I correct the URL to http://[::1]:8899/myProject/login by hand, it show the right page.

I want it redirect to http://[::1]:8899/myProject/login automatically.

Should I change any setting in config?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you please check your `base_url` in `config folder -> config.php`.
If you config your `base_url` with port number you will not face this issue

Comment: You need to set your base url in the config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8899/myProject/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your issue.

Go to Config Folder -> `Config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].'/myProject/';
```

then use like below.

```
redirect(base_url('login'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem. However in my another project (CI version is old), I don't even need to change config, even other setting, redirect still work very well... How strange

Answer (score 0):

Change the base_url like this.
it will be easy and no need to change the code wh

$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/appname/';